# How to keep this navbar in the center?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a header and above it I have my navbar. On my editor it is centered but when I stretch the page or view it in a different format it won't appear to be on top of the center of the header. Any ideas on what I should do?

```css
#nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:50px;
  }

#nav li{
  float:left;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: darkorange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom:none;
  
}

#nav a:hover{
  background-color: orangered;
}

#nav a:active{
  color:black;
}

#header{
  height:150px;
  background-color:darkred;
  margin-top:45px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

#innerheader{
  background-color:burlywood;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:50%;
  border-radius:25px;
  border:3px solid black;
  position:Relative;
  margin-top:22px;
}

#innerheader h1{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:30px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width:0.6px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color:black;
  color:saddlebrown;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Statistics</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com"> Biography </a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="header">
      <div id="innerheader">
        <h1>
         General Information
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Much of what I provided will not be useful to this question, and I apologize for that, but I just want to provide as much information as possible to get help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now try to this css

```
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block; // add this 
    font-size: 14px;    // add this 
}
#header {
    /* margin-top: 45px; */   // remove this line
}
```

**Demo**

```css
#nav {
list-style-type: none;
/* position: absolute; */
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
/* margin-left: 50px; */
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
}
#nav li {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
}
#header {
height: 150px;
background-color: darkred;
/* margin-top: 45px; */
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: darkorange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom:none;
  
}

#nav a:hover{
  background-color: orangered;
}

#nav a:active{
  color:black;
}


#innerheader{
  background-color:burlywood;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:50%;
  border-radius:25px;
  border:3px solid black;
  position:Relative;
  margin-top:22px;
}

#innerheader h1{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:30px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width:0.6px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color:black;
  color:saddlebrown;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Statistics</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com"> Biography </a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="header">
      <div id="innerheader">
        <h1>
         General Information
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm wondering as to why I'd remove position:absolute  and margin-top:45px  though. Any explanation would be great. I apologize since I am still new to CSS and am learning.

Comment: @StephenLandaas Welcome to you ... please read carefullly and understand css or html structure

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to your existing classes.

```
#nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }

#nav li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

This should solve your issue. 
Make your nav bar take full width, and center the inner contents horizontally using `text-align:center;`